# Snowflake CTE repeat each parent and child row of all possible combinations

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, common-table-expression, hierarchical-data

I would like to produce hierarchical output in Snowflake using a CTE. Here are my two tables `Dimension_territory` and `territory_member_list` :

The dimension `testdb.dbo.dimension_territory` contains the territory keys and the territory name

```
create table testdb.dbo.dimension_territory ( 
    territory_key integer, 
    territory_name varchar ) ;
```

Here `(1, 'World Wide')` is the root

```
insert into testdb.dbo.dimension_territory values 
    (1, 'WorldWide'),
    (2, 'Western Hemisphere'),
    (3, 'North America'),
    (4, 'Canada') ;
```

The `territory_member_list` table contains the parent child relations.

```
create table testdb.dbo.territory_member_list (
     parent_territory_key integer, 
     child_territory_key integer );


insert into testdb.dbo.territory_member_list values 
    (1, 2), -- WorldWide , Western Hemisphere 
    (2, 3), -- Western Hemisphere , North America , North america under Western hemisphere 
    (3, 4) -- North America ,Canada , Canada under North America
```

In the first entry into `testdb.dbo.territory_member_list (1, 2), -- WorldWide -> Western Hemisphere` the value 1 'WordlWide' is the parent of 2 'Western Hemisphere' (child) and likewise

The expected output of the CTE to derive the ancestors and the descendants should be the following table. Any help would be highly appreciated. Output table with the desired fields:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using "breadcrumb" array as helper structure to determine position in the path(naive approach):

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
   SELECT dt.*, tml.parent_territory_key
   FROM dimension_territory dt 
   LEFT JOIN territory_member_list tml
    ON tml.child_territory_key = dt.territory_key
), rec AS (
   SELECT cte.TERRITORY_KEY, cte.TERRITORY_NAME, cte.parent_territory_key,
          ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(cte.TERRITORY_KEY) AS a, 0 AS lvl
   FROM cte
   WHERE PARENT_TERRITORY_KEY IS NULL
   UNION ALL
   SELECT cte.TERRITORY_KEY, cte.TERRITORY_NAME, cte.parent_territory_key,
          ARRAY_APPEND(rec.a, cte.TERRITORY_KEY), lvl+1
   FROM rec
   JOIN cte ON rec.TERRITORY_KEY = cte.parent_territory_key
), lognest_path AS (
   SELECT * FROM rec QUALIFY lvl = MAX(lvl) OVER()
), cartesian AS (
  SELECT dt1.TERRITORY_KEY AS ANCESTOR_KEY, dt1.TERRITORY_NAME AS ANCESTOR_NAME,
         dt2.TERRITORY_KEY AS DESCENDANT_KEY, dt2.TERRITORY_NAME AS DESCENDANT_NAME
  FROM dimension_territory dt1
  CROSS JOIN dimension_territory dt2
)
SELECT DISTINCT c.*, lp.a,
      ARRAY_POSITION(c.ancestor_key,lp.a) AS a_p, 
      ARRAY_POSITION(c.descendant_key, lp.a) AS d_p,
      a_p = 0 AND d_p = 0 AS IS_ROOT,
      d_p - a_p AS EDGE_DISTANCE
FROM cartesian c
JOIN lognest_path lp 
  ON ARRAY_POSITION(c.ancestor_key,lp.a) >= 0
 AND ARRAY_POSITION(c.descendant_key, lp.a) >=0
WHERE a_p <= d_p
ORDER BY ANCESTOR_KEY, DESCENDANT_KEY;
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So because I used two CTE's for my fake tables/data, to use the [Recursive CTE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/queries-cte.html) which seems to bug out if it's not the first item after the WITH, I poked that into a sub-CTE. Once the relationships are built by that we can double join the dimensions again to get the names.

```
WITH dimension_territory(territory_key, territory_name) AS (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES
        (1, 'WorldWide'),
        (2, 'Western Hemisphere'),
        (3, 'North America'),
        (4, 'Canada')
), territory_member_list(parent_territory_key, child_territory_key) AS (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES
      (1, 2),
      (2, 3),
      (3, 4)
), h_cte AS (
    WITH RECURSIVE hierarchy(p_key, c_key, is_root, edge_distance) AS (
        -- Anchor Clause
        SELECT territory_key
            ,territory_key
            ,territory_key = 1
            ,0
        FROM dimension_territory
        --WHERE parent_territory_key = 1

        UNION ALL

        -- Recursive Clause
        SELECT h.p_key
            ,ml.child_territory_key
            ,false
            ,edge_distance + 1
        FROM territory_member_list AS ml
        JOIN hierarchy AS h
            ON ml.parent_territory_key = h.c_key --OR ml.child_territory_key = 

    )
    SELECT * FROM hierarchy
)
SELECT d_p.territory_key as ancestor_territory_key
    ,d_p.territory_name as ancestor_territory_name
    ,d_c.territory_key as descendant_territory_key
    ,d_c.territory_name as descendant_territory_name
    ,h.is_root
    ,h.edge_distance
FROM h_cte as h
JOIN dimension_territory AS d_p
   ON h.p_key = d_p.territory_key
JOIN dimension_territory AS d_c
   ON h.c_key = d_c.territory_key      
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

gives:

```
ANCESTOR_TERRITORY_KEY  ANCESTOR_TERRITORY_NAME DESCENDANT_TERRITORY_KEY    DESCENDANT_TERRITORY_NAME   IS_ROOT EDGE_DISTANCE
1   WorldWide           1   WorldWide           TRUE    0
1   WorldWide           2   Western Hemisphere  FALSE   1
1   WorldWide           3   North America       FALSE   2
1   WorldWide           4   Canada              FALSE   3
2   Western Hemisphere  2   Western Hemisphere  FALSE   0
2   Western Hemisphere  3   North America       FALSE   1
2   Western Hemisphere  4   Canada              FALSE   2
3   North America       3   North America       FALSE   0
3   North America       4   Canada              FALSE   1
4   Canada              4   Canada              FALSE   0
```

Because your wanted output is want the sub tree of every node, I select all nodes from `dimension_territory` in the Anchor Clause, which allows setting `is_root` via the assumption `1` is root, and setting each distance at 0. From there Recursive Clause is joining the recursive data with the edge list, to build the set of desendants.

So to get rid of the "data" CTE's this would look like:

```
WITH RECURSIVE hierarchy(p_key, c_key, is_root, edge_distance) AS (
    -- Anchor Clause
    SELECT territory_key
        ,territory_key
        ,territory_key = 1
        ,0
    FROM dimension_territory

    UNION ALL

    -- Recursive Clause
    SELECT h.p_key
        ,ml.child_territory_key
        ,false
        ,edge_distance + 1
    FROM territory_member_list AS ml
    JOIN hierarchy AS h
        ON ml.parent_territory_key = h.c_key --OR ml.child_territory_key = 
)
SELECT d_p.territory_key as ancestor_territory_key
    ,d_p.territory_name as ancestor_territory_name
    ,d_c.territory_key as descendant_territory_key
    ,d_c.territory_name as descendant_territory_name
    ,h.is_root
    ,h.edge_distance
FROM hierarchy as h
JOIN dimension_territory AS d_p
   ON h.p_key = d_p.territory_key
JOIN dimension_territory AS d_c
   ON h.c_key = d_c.territory_key      
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

Comment: Thanks a million Simeon for your fast response and explaining the solutions! That's exactly what I needed. Please let me know the significance of the 'SELECT * FROM hierarchy' statement between the 'h_cte' and the final select.

Comment: @Vids the cte `h_cte` needs to select something, it has two of it's own nested CTE the recursion, so the `SELECT * FROM hiearchy` is just get all from the recursive CTE and making it present in the `h_cte` CTE

Comment: Thanks Simeon for explaining with an example! Appreciate your help very much!